# Queries on implementing auto renewable in app purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

My application is going to have non consumable and auto renewable subscription. I am using individual song purchase via non consumable in app. and planned to sell songs ( group of songs ) via subscription also.

I have implemented non consumable in app purchase in my application.The way i did is as follows

```
1) Stored product identifiers from my web server.

2) fetched and displayed the products.

3) when the user taps "buy" for single song, the payment will be done and i will check the 
transaction receipt with apple server using my webserver.

4) if the receipt status is 0, i will make entry into my webserver database as that particular user has purchased that particular song.( by sending user id and product identifer)

5) then i deliver the content.
```

this is how i done.Now i am started implementing auto renewable subscription.generate shared secret and stored in iphone app.

as per the docs, when verifying the transaction receipt with the apple server, need to send the shared secret also.Now i would like to know below things

```
1) does my non consumable in app purchase makes sense? or am i left anything?

2) for the auto renewable subscription, once the transaction receipt is valid, what are the information i need to store in my web server.i mean, how can i know when the subscription going to expire, expire date, etc ?

3) how to check whether the subscription is valid before delivering the content?

4) if my steps to do are wrong pls suggest me how can i proceed? please share your opinion
sorry to be dumb
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I think for Non-Consumables, that makes sense. As you only buy them once, entering the info into your webserver database should be fine.
2. The transaction receipt is exactly your source of information: It is not "once valid", but to find out whether the subscription has expired, you should store the receipt. At every startup of your app (because this is resource-consuming), you can then send the receipts to Apple again "for validation" - in fact, this checks whether the subscription is still active with Appe (i.e. has been renewed in due time). The answer coming back from Apple contains (in a JSON dictionary) the information about the expiry date etc. (see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2)
3. You can then store the info whether the subscription is active somewhere in your app (non-permanently), so you know whether to deliver content during the actual run.